# Error printing PDF file using C# .NET Rest API in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, operating-system, windows-server-2012

I'm going through both scenarios:

I have a C# .NET Framework ASP.NET Rest API which saves a PDF file to the disk and sends it to Printer.

- Locally, logged directly in Windows 10 64 Bits, getting successful using  [Ghostscript 9.22 for Windows (32 bit)](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) driver and [Ghostcript.NET](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/) library, sending a file to Network Printer and out of NetWork, using AcrobatReader as a PDF file sender to the default printer.

Sending TXT file to the shared Printer on Network, the file is printed. At this point using C# code:

```
     System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, "\\\\" + printerIP + "\\" + printerName);
```

- Remotely, connecting to remote Windows Server 2012 R2 Machine using  [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/), failed in the two scenarios:
  Using Ghostscript, the API loops indefinitely and don't responses my API Call. Using Acrobat Reader, the application behavior is correct (the process starts and wait for 10 seconds which is reasonable to print a file), without loops or application exceptions, but doesn't print the file.

Testing in Windows Server 2012 R2, targeting the real scenario of API application which is called from a Tablet, this behavior is observed too.

I noted the Acrobat Reader not open the file as happened in success scenario locally, using Windows 10.

For the purpose, I disabled the Firewall and Antivirus to facilitate the analysis.

At this moment I am searching for considerations to solve this problem, trying to make the printing PDF File work in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `System.IO.File.Copy("\\\\PrinterIp\\PrinterName\\" + pathToFile);` Is there really only one parameter to that method?

Comment: @mjwills my problem is not this detail, TXT it's Ok in any scenario, PDF using Adobe or Ghostscript that fails. My difficulty is doing it work on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Windows Security Architecture seems not allows Asp Net API to access COM devices as a Printer directly, without the use of Impersonation. Through using Third Party libraries and a local printer connected to Computer with a higher level of intranet user as IIS User, the system printed the file. The best answer ( source code implementation, in my opinion, clearly and reusable without great "refactory effort" at the point of my need ) was obtained developing a Windows Service Program (installed as Admin user which have access to COM devices) that watches a directory and sends your content to the printer using another program as Adobe Reader. The target Printer for my real scenario was an IP Printer, not a local Printer.